# Reference attribute within same reserouce

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to reference an attribute within the same resource?

```
resource "some_resource" "foo" {
  name = "cool-name"

  attribute1 = "something-else-cool"
  attribute2 = format("%s-%s", this.name, this.attribute1)
}
```

Comment: Usually it is not possible, except in some special cases.

Comment: @MarkoE what are those special cases? is there any documentation? I haven't found much on the Hashicorp site or here

Comment: It usually depends on the provider, and you haven't specified one in your example. In AWS for example, there are cases where you could use `self` reference in an EC2 instance resource.

Comment: @MarkoE got it! thanks. I would have expected it to be a language feature rather than a provider feature.

Comment: Just for reference: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#how-to-use-provisioners. Look for `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it (at least with the current terraform versions).

Instead you can use [local values](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals):

```
locals {
  value1 = "something-else-cool"
  name   = "cool-name"
}

resource "some_resource" "foo" {
  name = local.name

  attribute1 = local.value1
  attribute2 = format("%s-%s", local.name, local.value1)
}
```

Or simple just use [input variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables)

```
resource "some_resource" "foo" {
  name = var.name

  attribute1 = var.someVariable
  attribute2 = format("%s-%s", var.name, var.someVariable)
}

variable "name" {
  type = string
  default = "value"
}

variable "someVariable" {
  type = string
  default = "value"
}
```

Or, you may want to look in your provisioner's documentation if it offers [`data sources`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources) in case you want to fetch data from you cloud setup.

---

Note that you can use [`self`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references#self) in provisioner and connection blocks, for example

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo The server's IP address is ${self.private_ip}"
  }
}
```